# How to get the name of the object that is calling the method in java?

Tags: java, this

I tried to create a method that *prints* the '**name of the object**' that is calling the method along with the '**field value**' of the same object.

```java
class ProgLang {
    String language;

    // Constructor to set the language field of the object as per the argument given
    ProgLang(String lang) {
        this.language = lang;
    }

    // method to check the field of an object
    void getField() {
        System.out.println("\n Programming Language of "+ this + " : " + this.language);
    }
}

public class ConstructorOverLoading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a instance of ProgLang class
        ProgLang obj1 = new ProgLang("Python");

        // get the value of the language field
        obj1.getField();

    }
}
```

And the output I expected was:-

```
Programming Language of obj1 : Python
```

But the output was:-

```
Programming Language of ProgLang@2f92e0f4 : Python
```

I am a noob in Java OOP. I tried to lookup the internet and I read about `getName()` method, so i replaced the `this` with `this.getName()` which ended up giving an error.

How do I print the name of the object that is calling the method?

Comment: I'm not quite sure 'object calling the method' is correct wording! I Apologize in advance

Comment: That's not possible. What do you expect to happen if I did `new ProgLang("Python").getField()`? What's the "name" in this case?

Comment: By the way, objects don't naturally have names. Variables do, but variables themselves are not objects.

Comment: I am not familiar with getField() method! Sorry! I'm a noob.

Comment: You literally wrote `getField` yourself.

Comment: So, there is no way to get the output i desired?

Comment: if you need the instance to have a name, you must add a `name` field to that class (similar to the `language` field in posted code)

Comment: @Sweeper it was getName()

Comment: Can you provide me a link where i can learn about name field and all? I don't even know what i should be asking to get the answer

Comment: @user16320675 to i meant

Comment: `ProgLang@2f92e0f4` is printed because you did not override `toString()` of `ProgLang`, but what you actually want is impossible. Variable names are practically only of meaning in the source (though that is a simplification), in any case, you cannot know inside `ProgLang` the name of the variable the object was assigned to (and a single object can be assigned to many variables, or none at all, so which should it use?)

Answer (score 2):

###### 1. programs don't care about variable names

You can name it `obj1` or `a` or whatever. We usually use meaningful names like `pythonLang` because it is easier to understand **by people**.

###### 2. when executing code, jvm uses `slot` to store variables

for code like this:

```
int a= 2;
int b= 3;
int c= a + b;
```

it will be executed like below:

```
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: iconst_2
         1: istore_1
         2: iconst_3
         3: istore_2
         4: iload_1
         5: iload_2
         6: iadd
         7: istore_3
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 473: 0
        line 474: 2
        line 475: 4
        line 485: 8
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       9     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
            2       7     1     a   I
            4       5     2     b   I
            8       1     3     c   I
```

STEP1: load constant 2, then store it to slot1

STEP2: load constant 3, store it to slot2

STEP3: load slot1 and slot2

STEP4: call iadd (add 2 number on top of [operand stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427056/16702058)), and store to slot3. And then return

###### 3.Slots can be reused if two local variables have limited scopes that don't overlap

for code like this:

```
if (true) {
    ProgLang obj1 = new ProgLang("Python");
    obj1.getField();
}
if (true) {
    ProgLang obj2 = new ProgLang("Python");
    obj2.getField();
}
```

it will be executed like:

```
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class ProgLang
         3: dup
         4: ldc           #3                  // String Python
         6: invokespecial #4                  // Method ProgLang."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         9: astore_1
        10: aload_1
        11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method ProgLang.getField:()V
        14: new           #2                  // class ProgLang
        17: dup
        18: ldc           #3                  // String Python
        20: invokespecial #4                  // Method ProgLang."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        23: astore_1
        24: aload_1
        25: invokevirtual #5                  // Method ProgLang.getField:()V
        28: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 475: 0
        line 476: 10
        line 479: 14
        line 480: 24
        line 482: 28
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           10       4     1  obj1   LProgLang;
           24       4     1  obj2   LProgLang;
            0      29     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
```

As you can see in the LocalVariableTable section, there are only two slots. slot0 is used for system args, and slot1 is used for both obj1 and obj2.

Since variable name is kind of irrelevant to code, so it will not be printed.

###### 4. If you really want to differentiate obj1, then add another field, for example `name` or `variableName`, to the Class

```
class ProgLang {
    String variableName;
    String language;

    ProgLang(String lang, String variableName) {
        this.language = lang;
        this.variableName = variableName;
    }

    void getField() {
        System.out.println("\n Programming Language of " + this.variableName + " : " + this.language);
    }
}

class ConstructorOverLoading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProgLang obj1 = new ProgLang("Python", "obj1");
        obj1.getField();
        ProgLang obj2 = new ProgLang("Python", "obj2");
        obj2.getField();
    }
}

// Programming Language of obj1 : Python
// Programming Language of obj2 : Python
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and explaining in detail.

Comment: Not trying to sound obtuse, but “_add another field, for example name or variableName, to the Class_” is all the advice OP needed. The rest of the story seems completely redundant.